# CSS - Можно ли объединить классы относящиеся к родительскому элементу?

Tags: css, css3

Дано:

```
<div id="a">
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
</div>
<div id="b">
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div>
```

Перевести в:

```
#a .a {
//стиль
}
#a .b {
//стиль
}
#b .a {
//стиль
}
#b .b {
//стиль
}
```

Надо что-то типа:

```
#a {
.a {
//стиль
}
.b {
//стиль
}
}
#b {
.a {
//стиль
}
.b {
//стиль
}
}
```

Comment: Так можно, если ты будешь писать в `less || scss`... `css` такой синтаксис не поймет

Answer (score 4):

В чистом CSS такого сделать нельзя.

Используйте препроцессоры [sass](https://sass-lang.com), [less](http://lesscss.org) или постпроцессор [postcss](https://postcss.org)

Comment: + [stylus](http://stylus-lang.com/)